# Problemas com login

Tags: php

Estou com problemas no meu cadastro de login não consigo validar a senha ele esta incorreto mas o banco de dados ele esta correto

```
<?php 

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "angola") or die("cannot connect");
$con= mysql_select_db("login_senha");

$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$enviar = $_POST['enviar'];

$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  login='$login'");


while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $senha =$linha['senha'];
}
$cont = mysql_num_rows($sql);


 if($cont==0){
     echo"
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content= '0; url=cadastro.php'/>
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>alert ('Login não existe')</script>
    ";
 }else{
      if($senha_db!=$senha){ // <---------- esta é a linha 27
        echo"
        <meta http-equiv='refresh' content= '0; url=cadastro.php'/>
        <script type = 'text/javascript'>alert ('Senha não corresponde')</script>
    "; 
       }else{
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['login_usuario']=$login;
         $_SESSION['login_senha']=$senha;
         header("Location: ficha.php");
     }
 }
 mysql_close($db);



?>
```

ele da esta seguinte mensagem.

> Undefinide variavel line 27

Comment: De onde vem `$senha_db`?

Comment: Qual é a linha 27?

Answer (score 1):

Tente elaborar da seguinte forma:

```
session_start();    
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "angola") or die("cannot connect");
$con= mysql_select_db("login_senha");

$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha_post = $_POST['senha'];
$enviar = $_POST['enviar'];

$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  login='$login'");
$cont = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($cont==0){ 
        echo"
        <meta http-equiv='refresh' content= '0; url=cadastro.php'/>
        <script type = 'text/javascript'>alert ('Login não existe')</script>
        ";
    } else { 
        while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            if($linha['senha']!=$senha_post){
                echo "
                <meta http-equiv='refresh' content= '0; url=cadastro.php'/>
                <script type = 'text/javascript'>alert ('Senha não corresponde')</script>
                "; 
            } else {
                $_SESSION['login_usuario']=$login;
                $_SESSION['login_senha']=$senha;
                header("Location: ficha.php");
            }
        }
}

mysql_close($db);
```

Comment: Muito obriga pela ajuda, deu certo

Comment: Ok, por favor marque minha resposta como correta. Muito obrigado!